# About Handling Events in Unity

Tags: events, unity-game-engine, event-handling, abstract-class

I have an abstract class which has an abstract event listener method. I override this method in each script derived from this base class. But this way every time my event got triggered all scripts compulsorily listen to it and i have to check which script must response this call via passed parameter of method. Knowing this made me feel uncomfortable. But if i do not choose this way i have to declare different listener methods for each script individually. This also makes me feel uncomfortable.

In fact i was handling this event in game manager but according to single responsibility im trying to lighten game managers burden so i seperated this event to related scripts. But handling one particular event in each script differently also doesn't fit in single responsibility much. This is much like combining all related responsibilities under a script.

One another way is using an EventHandler class. But this time i have to declare all related scripts(each object using this script as component and all their properties) in EventHandler. So this doesn't sound very uncomfortable too.

To sum up i basically want to know whats is the less uncomfortable way :) ?

Thanks in advence..

**In addition to my previous post:**

```
public abstract class SomeEvent{
            .
            .
   public abstract void OnTrigger(someparameter)
}

public class GameObject1 : SomeEvent{
   public override void OnTrigger(someparameter){
      if(someParameter is related to GameObject1){
         do Something;
      }
   } 
}
```

- This is first alternative. I'll repeat the same process for all
  other scrips drived from SomeEvent
- Second alternative defining seperate events for each different
  objects script which means one more event for an additional script everytime. It's like gameobject1 --> gameobject1event, gameobject2 --> gameobject2event etc.
- Third alternative is create an EventHandler class and do something like below:

Here it is

```
public class EventHandler{

    GameObject GameObject1;
    GameObject GameObject2...

    void OnTrigger(someparameter){
        if(someParameter is related to GameObject1){
            do Something;
        }else if(someParameter is related to GameObject2){
            do another thing;
        }so on...
    }
}
```

I already told my worries about these three ways. Hope these pseudos make it more understandable.

Comment: Editing your question and posting the current code you have, with all your events, will make somebody respond to yoy with a better code.

Comment: " But this way every time my event got triggered all scripts
compulsorily listen to it"

How is this happening? it shouldn't be like this. if you paste a sample code i can help you better.

Comment: I mean all scripts that overrides abstract event method